# acroform field.setRichTextValue is not working

Tags: pdfbox, richtext

I have a field from acroform and I see `field.setValue()` and `field.setRichTextValue(...)`. The first one set the correct value, but second one seems not working, rich text value is not display.
Here is code im using :

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(SRC));
            pdfDocument.getDocument().setIsXRefStream(true);
            PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            acroForm.setNeedAppearances(false);

            acroForm.getField("tenantDataValue").setValue("Deuxième texte");
            acroForm.getField("tradingAddressValue").setValue("Text replacé");
            acroForm.getField("buildingDataValue").setValue("Deuxième texte");
            acroForm.getField("oldRentValue").setValue("750");
            acroForm.getField("oldChargesValue").setValue("655");
            acroForm.getField("newRentValue").setValue("415");
            acroForm.getField("newChargesValue").setValue("358");
            acroForm.getField("increaseEffectiveDateValue").setValue("Texte 3eme contenu");


            // THIS RICH TEXT NOT SHOW ANYTHING
            PDTextField field = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("tableData");
            field.setRichText(true);
            String val = "\\rtpara[size=12]{para1}{This is 12pt font, while \\span{size=8}{this is 8pt font.} OK?}";
            field.setRichTextValue(val);
```

I expect field named "tableData" to be setted with rich text value!

You can download the PDF form I am using with this code : [download pdf form](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jFbsYGFOnx8EMiHgDsE8LQtfwJHSa5Gh)
 and you can download the output after runn this code and flatten form data [download output here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EVJW0YVga7cqzY8AvfO3732qQC0iw4C6)

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Nothing happened (what should have happened?), crash, exception, freeze, PC power down, nuclear explosion, or did you end in a time loop?

Comment: Ahaha @TilmanHausherr nop nothing happend...i dont know how it needs to work? I am trying to set basic string value on pdf output nothing is changed any doc about how it wors and qhat is called rich text value, thank you for response

Comment: Please share your PDF; Could you please clarify what you mean with "on pdf output nothing is changed any doc about how it wors and qhat is called rich text value". What is "pdf output" - view with Adobe Reader? With another software? Normally one just calls `field.setValue()` and that one sets the visual appearance except if `acroForm.getNeedAppearances()` is true. See also the many examples in the source code download in the example subproject.

Comment: I finally understand what you meant with "any doc about how it wors and qhat is called rich text value". Have a look at the PDF 32000 specification, page 436, 12.7.3.4 Rich Text Strings. PDFBox doesn't use it to generate the visual appearance, but maybe other tools do.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr it seems pdfbox has this method but on chrone viewer it doesnt set anything. After quick read here http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/richtext/doc/richtextman.pdf it seems pdfbox only set value but pdf parser reader should interpret it not pdfbox. So thats why i cant understand qhy pdfbox provide methode and nothing happen when set simple rich text value.

Comment: So your question really was "but second one has no effect on Chrome browser". (Why didn't you write this in your question?) So maybe it is a pdfium bug. Btw you also need to set the rich text flag, `setRichText(true)`. It is very difficult to understand questions when you have no PDF, no code, and no details. Setting the value will tell a "conforming reader" (Adobe Reader, and a few others) how to generate the appearance stream. That's even explained in the javadoc of `setRichTextValue()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr please apologize I edited the question with code and with links to download, I admit I was wrong asking thing without theses infos. Just to be clear I was trying open pdf with Acrobat Reader and this field named "tableData" not showing anything in pdf! thank you in advance

Comment: Your rich text does not at all look like rich text as pdf understands it.

Comment: @mkl  oh really ? i was thinking this is, i copied from herehttp://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/richtext/doc/richtextman.pdf please what is the correct value for rich text, where can I find something ?

Comment: If you flattened it after setting the richtext nothing special will happen for sure. The javadoc itself says that richtext does not change the appearance. I thought you were setting richtextvalue and then displaying it with chrome. So your question is really "acroform field.setRichTextValue makes no difference when flattening". The javadoc itself tells `Setting the rich text value will not generate the appearance for the field` and it is used `to signal a conforming reader to generate the appearance stream`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you but as i said it is not with chrome but acrobat reader. and i have same result without flatten statement

Comment: @bee That `\rtpara` is a *LaTeX command* from the **richtext** package which internally creates the rich text as PDF understands it. For that have a look at the (surprise, surprise!) *PDF specification*! E.g. the copy of ISO 32000-1 published by Adobe [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), section 12.7.3.4 "Rich Text Strings".

Comment: And for Adobe Reader to generate appearances you might want to use `acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true)` to ask the viewer to do so.

Comment: Oh, looking at your PDF output you appear to flatten the form afterwards. If that is required, you're out-of-luck with PDFBox as of today, cf. @Tilman's JavaDoc quote.

Comment: weird setting to my field `field.setRichText(true);` then instead of `setRichTextValue` simply using `field.setValue("<body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><p style=\"color:#FF0000;\">Red&#13;</p><p style=\"color:#1E487C;\">Blue&#13;</p></body>")` works ! in acrobat reader (without flatten) the field is correctly formatted, even if document version is 1.4, it seems this setRichTextValue have no effect using setValue works (but yes my problem now is I need flatten data) lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To sum up what has been said in the comments to the question plus some studies of the working version...*

#### Wrong rich text format

The OP in his original code used this as rich text

```java
String val = "\\rtpara[size=12]{para1}{This is 12pt font, while \\span{size=8}{this is 8pt font.} OK?}";
```

which he took from [this document](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/richtext/doc/richtextman.pdf). But that document is the manual for the LaTeX **richtext** package which *provides commands and documentation needed to “easily” produce such rich strings.* I.e. the `\rtpara...` above is *not* PDF rich text but *instead* a LaTeX command that *produces* PDF rich text (if executed in a LaTeX context).

The document actually even demonstrates this using the example

```
\rtpara[indent=first]{para1}{Now is the time for
    \span{style={bold,italic,strikeit},color=ff0000}{J\374rgen}
    and all good men to come to the aid of \it{their}
    \bf{country}. Now is the time for \span{style=italic}
    {all good} women to do the same.}
```

for which the instruction generates two values, a rich text value and a plain text value:

```html
\useRV{para1}: <p dir="ltr" style="text-indent:12pt;
    margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;">Now is the time
    for <span style="text-decoration:line-through;
    font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;
    ">J\374rgen</span> and all good men to come to the
    aid of <i>their</i> <b>country</b>. Now is the
    time for <span style="font-style:italic;">all
    good</span> women to do the same.</p>
\useV{para1}: Now is the time for J\374rgen and all
    good men to come to the aid of their country. Now
    is the time for all good women to do the same.
```

As one can see in the `\useRV{para1}` result, PDF rich text uses (cut down) HTML markup for rich text.

For more details please lookup the PDF specification, e.g. section 12.7.3.4 "Rich Text Strings" in the copy of ISO 32000-1 published by Adobe [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

#### PDFBox does not create rich text appearances

The OP in his original code uses

```java
acroForm.setNeedAppearances(false);
```

This sets a flag that claims that all form fields have appearance streams (in which the visual appearance of the respective form field plus its content are elaborated) and that these streams represent the current value of the field, so it effectively tells the next processor of the PDF that it can use these appearance streams as-is and does not need to generate them itself.

As @Tilman quoted from the JavaDocs, though,

```java
/**
 * Set the fields rich text value.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Setting the rich text value will not generate the appearance
 * for the field.
 * <br>
 * You can set {@link PDAcroForm#setNeedAppearances(Boolean)} to
 * signal a conforming reader to generate the appearance stream.
 * </p>
 * 
 * Providing null as the value will remove the default style string.
 * 
 * @param richTextValue a rich text string
 */
public void setRichTextValue(String richTextValue)
```

So `setRichTextValue` does **not** create an appropriate appearance stream for the field. To signal the next processor of the PDF (in particular a viewer or form flattener) that it has to generate appearances, therefore, one needs to use

```java
acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);
```

#### Making Adobe Acrobat (Reader) generate the appearance from rich text

When asked to generate field appearances for a rich text field, Adobe Acrobat has the choice to do so either based on the rich text value **RV** or the flat text value **V**. I did some quick checks and Adobe Acrobat appears to use these strategies:

1. If **RV** is set and the value of **V** equals the value of **RV** without the rich text markup, Adobe Acrobat assumes the value of **RV** to be up-to-date and generates an appearance from this rich text string according to the PDF specification. *Else the value of **RV** (if present at all) is assumed to be outdated and ignored!*
2. Otherwise, if the **V** value contains rich text markup, Adobe Acrobat assumes this value to be rich text and creates the appearance according to this styling.

   *This is **not** according to the PDF specification.*

   Probably some software products used to falsely put the rich text into the **V** value and Adobe Acrobat started to support this misuse for larger compatibility.
3. Otherwise the **V** value is used as a plain string and an appearance is generated accordingly.

This explains why the OP's original approach using only

```java
field.setRichTextValue(val);
```

showed no change - the rich text value was ignored by Adobe Acrobat.

And it also explains his observation

> then instead of `setRichTextValue` simply using `field.setValue("<body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><p style=\"color:#FF0000;\">Red&#13;</p><p style=\"color:#1E487C;\">Blue&#13;</p></body>")` works ! in acrobat reader (without flatten) the field is correctly formatted

Be aware, though, that this is beyond the PDF specification. If you want to generate valid PDF, you have to set both **RV** and **V** and have the latter contain the plain version of the rich text of the former.

For example use

```java
String val = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
        + "<body xfa:APIVersion=\"Acroform:2.7.0.0\" xfa:spec=\"2.1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:xfa=\"http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/\">"
        + "<p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12pt\">"
        + "This is 12pt font, while "
        + "<span style=\"font-size:8pt\">this is 8pt font.</span>"
        + " OK?"
        + "</p>"
        + "</body>";
String valClean = "This is 12pt font, while this is 8pt font. OK?";
field.setValue(valClean);
field.setRichTextValue(val);
```

or

```java
String val = "<body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><p style=\"color:#FF0000;\">Red&#13;</p><p style=\"color:#1E487C;\">Blue&#13;</p></body>";
String valClean = "Red\rBlue\r";
field.setValue(valClean);
field.setRichTextValue(val);
```